How to dynamically build an Angular FormGroup based on an asynchronous condition and adjust its validators
I’m working on a form in Angular where I need to dynamically build a FormGroup based on a condition that is retrieved asynchronously through an effect. The condition (sameServices) determines if an additional field, addressComplement, should be included in the form and be required.
Here is my code:
constructor(private shared: Shared) {
  effect(() => {
    this.business = this.shared.getBusiness();
  });

  if (this.business.sameServices) {
    this.branchDataForm = new FormGroup({
      address: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
      addressComplement: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
    });
  } else {
    this.branchDataForm = new FormGroup({
      address: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])
    });
  }
}

My issues are:
The constructor does not wait for the effect to complete before executing the conditional.
If I place the conditional inside the effect, the HTML fails, indicating that it cannot find the controls since they are not yet defined at the time of template rendering.
I need the form to be valid only if the required fields are present and meet their validation rules based on the condition (sameServices).
Question
What would be a clean and efficient way to build a FormGroup in Angular based on an asynchronous condition, dynamically adding or removing controls and their validators? Are there best practices for handling this type of scenario in Angular?

You can try this approach, first we set all the possible controls during initial load, but we make sure that all of them are disabled, so that the form does not validate them.
branchDataForm = new FormGroup({
  address: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(3),
  ]),
  addressComplement: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(3),
  ]),
});

We make use of the [hidden] attribute, instead of ngIf which works great with reactive forms, we can do the job of hiding the hidden fields using this logic.
<form [formGroup]="branchDataForm">
  <input [hidden]="!showFields['address']" formControlName="address"/>    <br/><br/>
  <input [hidden]="!showFields['addressComplement']" formControlName="addressComplement"/><br/><br/>
</form>

Then after the signal completes, we simply enable the control using the below function. We also set the boolean which hides/shows the field.
enableFormFields(enableFields: Array<string>) {
  this.branchDataForm.disable();
  Object.keys(this.showFields).forEach((key: string) => {
    this.showFields[key] = false;
  });
  enableFields.forEach((controlName: string) => {
    const ctrl = this.branchDataForm.get(controlName);
    ctrl?.enable();
    this.showFields[controlName] = true;
  });
}

constructor() {
  effect(() => {
    this.business = this.getBusiness();
    if (this.business.sameServices) {
      this.enableFormFields(['address', 'addressComplement']);
    } else {
      this.enableFormFields(['address']);
    }
  });
}

Full Code:
import { Component, effect } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormControl,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { of, delay } from 'rxjs';
import { toSignal } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="branchDataForm">
      <input [hidden]="!showFields['address']" formControlName="address"/>    <br/><br/>
      <input [hidden]="!showFields['addressComplement']" formControlName="addressComplement"/><br/><br/>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  getBusiness = toSignal(
    of({
      sameServices: false,
    })
  );
  business: any;
  branchDataForm = new FormGroup({
    address: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
    ]),
    addressComplement: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
    ]),
  });
  noAddress = true;
  showFields: any = {};

  enableFormFields(enableFields: Array<string>) {
    this.branchDataForm.disable();
    Object.keys(this.showFields).forEach((key: string) => {
      this.showFields[key] = false;
    });
    enableFields.forEach((controlName: string) => {
      const ctrl = this.branchDataForm.get(controlName);
      ctrl?.enable();
      this.showFields[controlName] = true;
    });
  }

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      this.business = this.getBusiness();
      if (this.business.sameServices) {
        this.enableFormFields(['address', 'addressComplement']);
      } else {
        this.enableFormFields(['address']);
      }
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
